# ssh connection not working with fresh ubuntu 20.04.4 install

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, ssh

I just installed fresh ubuntu server from ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso in VMware and installed my ssh pub key into ubuntu host user $HOME.ssh/authorized_keys file. After couple of minutes my login session into ubuntu host gets terminated with 'client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe' and if try to re-connect I get 'Offending ECDSA key in...' error?
It does not help if I remove old host key or restart sshd, everything will repeat again in couple of minutes. I tried to search syslog and auth.log but there's nothing in there. I have newer seen this kind of behavior before?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure this  out, root cause is IP collision.